# Moving Report Server Databases to Another Drive

Tags: ssrs

Currently our Reporting Server Databases are in C:
So would like to place them in E:\RS\

Can I know how can I move the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB Database files from one location to another and things I should keep in mind before this operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be minimal downtime, so plan this in a maintenance window:

Don't use detach/attach!

1. Have verified backups!
2. Use `Alter database...modify file...` (do below for `mdf` and `ldf` files)

   ```
   use master;
   alter database dbname 
   modify file (
       name = 'logicalName', 
       filename = 'E:\RS\db_name.mdf'); --> This is the new file location
   ```
3. Now offline the database:

   ```
   alter database db_name set offline with rollback immediate;
   ```
4. Physically copy the mdf and ldf files to the new location.
5. Bring the database online:

   ```
   alter database db_name set online;
   ```

If you script out and test out on a dummy database, you will see how much time it takes and will build your confidence.

Answer (score 2):

1. Stop the Reporting Services service
2. In SSMS, Right-click `ReportServer --> tasks --> detach...`
3. In SSMS,Right-click `ReportServerTempDB --> tasks --> detach...`
4. In SSMS,Copy (not move) both associated mdf/ldf files to `E:\RS`
5. Right-click databases folder, `Attach...`
6. Restart the Reporting Services service

You should be good to go. If anything unforeseen happens, simply re-attach the databases on `C:`.